# Anime about a girl whose underwear was stolen by a ghost

Tags: story-identification, anime

This anime has an episode about a girl that was forced to wear her dad's underwear because all her underwear was stolen by a pervert ghost.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)